# Stop accountsd + Mail.app from completely obliterating my CPU when the internet drops

Tags: wifi, mail.app, catalina, internet

When I have Mail.app open, and I leave Wi-Fi range or my internet connectivity drops, the fans whirr up and CPU usage completely spikes (accountsd is using all the CPU, not Mail.app itself) and my laptop becomes too hot to touch.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: There may be a preference/setting that is causing this, you can try making a second (test) account, logging out of your regular account and logging into the new one and trying there. If that is it then I would remove all of the mail/accounts related preferences in your profile and setting those back up.